# Build a Fortran 90 wrapper for a Lapack subroutine

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, fortran90, lapack

This is the first time I try to use Lapack. I'm using Forgran 90, and I want to build an easy-to-use wrapper subroutine SVD(A, U, S, V) for me to use later on when calculation Singular Value Decomposition problems. In particular, I'm using the function DGESDD, and I'm basing my program in this [example](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgesdd_ex.f.htm), which I was able to compile and run.

The code I produced looks like this:

```
module Statistics

contains
subroutine SVD(a,u,s,v)
  real, dimension(:,:), intent(inout) :: a
  real, dimension(:,:), intent(out) :: u,v
  real, dimension(:), intent(out) :: s

  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: vt
  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: work
  integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: iwork
  integer :: lda, m, n, lwork, ldvt, info, mx, mn, lwmax=1000
  character(len=1) :: jobz

  m=size(a,1)
  n=size(a,2)

  mx=max(m,n)
  mn=min(m,n)

  jobz='a'
  lda=m
  ldu=m
  ldvt=n

  lwork=-1

  allocate(vt(n,n))
  allocate(work(lwmax))
  allocate(iwork(8*mn))
!  print*, 'a', shape(a)
!  print*, 'vt', shape(vt)
!  print*, 'u', shape(u)
!  print*, 'work', shape(work)
!  print*, 'iwork', shape(iwork)

  call dgesdd( jobz, m, n, a, lda, s, u, ldu, vt, ldvt, work, lwork, iwork, info )
  lwork = min( lwmax, int( work( 1 ) ) )
  print*, lwork
  call dgesdd(jobz, m, n, a, lda, s, u, ldu, vt, ldvt, work, lwork, iwork, info )

  v=transpose(vt)

  end subroutine SVD
end module Statistics

program test
  use Statistics
  external dgesdd

  real a(4,2),u(4,4),s(2),v(2,2)
  k=1
  do i=1,4
  do j=1,2
  a(i,j)=k*1.0d0
  k=k+1
  end do  
  end do
  write(*,*) 'a ='
  write(*,'(2f10.4)') ((a(i,j),j=1,2),i=1,4)

  call svd(a,u,s,v)

  write(*,*) 'u ='
  write(*,'(4f10.4)') ((u(i,j),j=1,4),i=1,4)

  write(*,*) 'v='
  write(*,'(2f10.4)') v
  write(*,*) 's =' 
  write(*,'(2f10.4)')s
end program test
```

But it refuses to work, although I do not see how it differs from the example above. The problem appears already when calling the subroutine the first time to query for the optimal size of iwork. It returns 0. Still, if I overwrite the value and I set it to something like 1000, then in the second call it leads to segmentation fault. It must be something silly having to do with matrix allocation, but I'm have tried many things and I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Damn, certainly good to see some Fortran questions as well... If I only were fluent in it...

Comment: Don't let me stop you, but you do know that many (well, a few any way) have already written Fortran 90 wrappers for LAPACK, don't you ?  Use your favourite search engine for *lapack90*, or, if you have a copy, look in the documentation for Intel's MKL package.

Comment: Well, as I say, I don't have much experience with this package, its structure, how it is distributed and so. I have searched a bit as you sugggest, but I find very old-school stuff. For instance, I seem to need LA_GESDD, which supposedly is part of the package you can get here http://www.netlib.org/lapack95/ (from year 2000!). But the subroutine does not seem to be part of the source code of the package. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are allocating REAL arrays, and DGESDD is expecting DOUBLE PRECISION.

Comment: Thanks @Jack this was indeed the issue, and effectively answers my question. I changed the routine to SGESDD and it works now. Perhaps you can upgrade your comment to answer, actually, so I can set it ans solved.